# Set default state after object has been loaded

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, use-state

I am using custom made useFirestore hook to retrieve file objects from my firestore collection.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { app } from "../firebase/firebase_storage";

const useFirestore = (collection) => {
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = app
      .firestore()
      .collection(collection)
      .onSnapshot((snap) => {
        let songsArr = [];
        snap.forEach((song) => {
          songsArr.push({ ...song.data(), id: song.id });
        });
        setSongs(songsArr);
      });

    return () => unsub();
  }, [collection]);

  return { songs };
};

export default useFirestore;
```

Then I am storing this collection into a variable

```
const tracks = useFirestore("songs");
```

console.log(tracks) is giving

```
{songs: Array(2)}
```

I want to set the first track to be the default one which will be loaded into the waveform and I am using  useState.

```
const [selectedTrack, setSelectedTrack] = useState(tracks.songs[0]);
```

This is not working because when the default state is set, the value I am passing is undefined because I am assuming it is not loaded. When I set some objects with placeholder data this works.

So my idea was that somehow postpone assigning default state until the object loads and it is not undefined.

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` and set default state after `tracks` is initialized.

Try:-

```
const tracks = useFirestore("songs");
const [selectedTrack, setSelectedTrack] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  setSelectedTrack(tracks.songs[0]);
}, [tracks])
```

Comment: Not working, I am getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`
`<Waveform url={selectedTrack.url} />`

Comment: can you try after changing default value as object in useState like `useState({})`

Comment: The library I am using, wavesurfer.js doesn't allow empty URL to be passed into load() method which eventually loads the audio.